# make different subplot have the same range of colors on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot several data on subplots, but each one have its own range of color (colorbar) and I want all to be the same. I can change the labels of the colorbar but if ranges are too different it would mostly show only one color. Is there a way to make matlab think that its all just one plot and then decide the colorbar scale accordingly?

To change colorbar label its quite easy:

```
allaxes = findall(f, 'type', 'axes');%f is the figure handle
for i=1:length(allaxes)
    cc=get(allaxes(i),'Colorbar');
    mm(i,:)=get(cc,'Limits');
end

limits=[min(min(mm)) max(max(mm))];
for i=1:length(allaxes)
    cc=get(allaxes(i),'Colorbar');
    set(cc,'Limits',limits);
end
```

Here there is an example (look for the one on the right):
[image: colorbar]
[image: "fixed" colorbar]

Comment: Change the axes’ CLimits instead (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html). The color bars adjust automatically and will show correct colors.

Comment: But it’s hard in your case because the ranges of data in the plots are so different. It will be hard to make this look nice on a single scale.

Comment: cool, thanks. That did the trick, not really helpful in the case of the example, but ti works fine on data with similar scaling